# How do I delete a marker and connected polylines from a Leaflet popup?

Tags: leaflet

I have placed several markers, and each marker is connected to the next with a polyline.

I want to click on the marker, open a popup, and then click a button which will then remove that marker and all connected polylines.

I will be showing information about each marker in the popup, so the marker removal option needs to be shown this way.

I've tried using `marker.on('click', onClick);` but that really wasn't giving me what I needed.

I'm storing the line coordinates in the markers's options, as `connectedLines`

I have placed all of the markers and lines, but my brain is stuck on how to remove the lines. I can't seem to retrieve the marker instance to the button in the popup.

```js
let coords = [[5654, 11659],[8274, 10847],[13374, 7801],[13956, 7563],[13801, 5943]];

let polylinePoints = [];

coords.forEach((item, index) => {
    marker = L.marker(map.unproject([item[0], item[1]], map.getMaxZoom()), {
        id: item[0]+item[1],
        connectedLines: []
    });

    if (index % 2 != 0) {
        polylinePoints.push(marker.getLatLng());
        marker.options.connectedLines.push(marker.getLatLng());
    } else {
        polylinePoints.push(marker.getLatLng());
        marker.options.connectedLines.push(marker.getLatLng());
    }
    
    marker.bindPopup('<button onclick="onClick()">Remove Marker</button>').addTo(map);
});

let polylines = L.polyline(polylinePoints).addTo(map);

function onClick(e) {
   // remove clicked marker and connected polylines
   // how to get the target data?
   // I have tried e.options, and e.target.options, but neither work
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to the map a `popupopen` listener and get from it the marker:

```
var popupMarker;
map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
  popupMarker = e.popup._source;
});

function onClick(e) {
   popupMarker.remove();
   popupMarker.options.connectedLines.forEach((line)=>{
      line.remove();
   });
}
```

Comment: I had to change `popupMarker.remove()` to `map.removeLayer(popupMarker)`, which is now working, but cannot get the lines to remove no matter what I try. Even trying `map.removeLayer(line)`

Comment: I just saw that you are creating only one polyline object -> `polylines`. You need to create for each line between markers a own polyline object and add this to `marker.options.connectedLines`. Currently you are only adding the marker coordinates into the array, but this is useless.

Comment: Yep. Realized that last night and am working on that right now. Thanks.

Comment: I've created a new question that better reflects what my problem is, if you want to take a stab at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74997061/how-do-i-create-a-proper-loop-to-remove-all-connected-leaflet-polylines. Thanks again!