# How do I create a proper loop to remove all connected leaflet polylines?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've created a Leaflet map with polylines.

As you can see in the GIF, when clicking from left to right (in the order the markers were added) the polylines are being removed, and it visually makes sense. However, when removing a random marker, only **one** line is being removed.

I've been working on this for two days and now my brain is stuck and I can't think past this.

How can I fix my loop so that **both** lines are removed?

[image: Removing polylines]

##### Here's a pen

https://codepen.io/timgavin/pen/JjBRdMq

##### Here's the loop

```js
// loop through the array of coordinates
coordinates.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (index < (coordinates.length - 1)) {
        
        // place the marker
        marker = L.marker(map.unproject([item[0], item[1]], map.getMaxZoom()), {
            polylines: []
        });
        
        // create and place the polylines
        polyline = L.polyline([
            map.unproject([item[0], item[1]], map.getMaxZoom()),
            map.unproject([coordinates[index+1][0], coordinates[index+1][1]], map.getMaxZoom())
        ]).addTo(map);
        
        // update the marker with the polylines
        marker.options.polylines.push(polyline);
        
        // place the marker on the map
        marker.bindPopup('<button onclick="removeMarker()">Remove</button>').addTo(map);
    } else {
        // this is the last marker in the array
        marker = L.marker(map.unproject([item[0], item[1]], map.getMaxZoom()), {
            polylines: []
        });
        
        marker.bindPopup('<button onclick="removeMarker()">Remove</button>').addTo(map);
    }
});
```

##### Code for removing the marker and polylines

```js
var popupMarker;

// get the clicked marker's instance
map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
    popupMarker = e.popup._source;
});

// remove the clicked marker and its attached polylines
function removeMarker(e) {
    map.removeLayer(popupMarker);
    popupMarker.options.polylines.forEach((line) => {
        map.removeLayer(line);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the polyline in a variable and then add it to the next marker:

```
var lastPolyline;
// loop through the array of coordinates
coordinates.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (index < coordinates.length - 1) {
    // place the marker
    marker = L.marker(map.unproject([item[0], item[1]], map.getMaxZoom()), {
      polylines: []
    });
    
    if(lastPolyline){
      marker.options.polylines.push(lastPolyline);
    }
    
    // create and place the polylines
    lastPolyline = L.polyline([
      map.unproject([item[0], item[1]], map.getMaxZoom()),
      map.unproject(
        [coordinates[index + 1][0], coordinates[index + 1][1]],
        map.getMaxZoom()
      )
    ]).addTo(map);

    // update the marker with the polylines
    marker.options.polylines.push(lastPolyline);

    // place the marker on the map
    marker
      .bindPopup('<button onclick="removeMarker()">Remove</button>')
      .addTo(map);
  } else {
    // this is the last marker in the array
    marker = L.marker(map.unproject([item[0], item[1]], map.getMaxZoom()), {
      polylines: []
    });
    
    if(lastPolyline){
      marker.options.polylines.push(lastPolyline);
    }

    marker
      .bindPopup('<button onclick="removeMarker()">Remove</button>')
      .addTo(map);
  }
});
```